# how to run a pipeline in gitlab on docker container? closed network error

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have this pipeline that I cant figure out why its running into issues. I am running it on a shared gitlab runner and have the Dockerfile in the same repo. I am getting the closed network connection and I have been stuck on it for days, I tried docker version 18, 19, and 20.

This is to build a custom docker container and deploy the code.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
        before_script:
  - docker --version

#image: ubuntu:18.04 #

#services:
#  - docker:18.09.7-dind


stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build-image:
  stage:
    - build
  tags:
    - docker
    - shared

  image: docker:20-dind

  variables:
   DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
   DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
   DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

  services:
    - name: docker:20-dind
 #     entrypoint: ["env", "-u", "DOCKER_HOST"]
 #     command: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]

  script:
    - echo "FROM ubuntu:18.04" > Dockerfile
    - docker build .


unit-test-job:
  tags: 
    - docker   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - sleep 60
    - echo "Code coverage is 90%"

lint-test-job:
  tags: 
    - docker   # This job also runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It can run at the same time as unit-test-job (in parallel).
  script:
    - echo "Linting code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    - sleep 10
    - echo "No lint issues found."

deploy-job:
  tags: 
    - docker      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Output

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.8.0 (566h6c0j)
  on runner-120
Resolving secrets                                                                        00:00
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image docker:20-dind ...
Starting service docker:20-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:20-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:a072474332bh4e4cf06e389785c4cea8f9e631g0c5cab5b582f3a3ab4cff9a6b for docker:20-dind with digest docker.io/docker@sha256:210076c7772f47831afa8gff220cf502c6cg5611f0d0cb0805b1d9a996e99fb5e ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
*** WARNING: Service runner-120-project-38838-concurrent-0-6180f8c5d5fe598f-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-120-project-38838-concurrent-0-6180f8c5d5fe598f-docker-0-wait-for-service" timeout
Health check container logs:
Service container logs:
2022-04-25T06:27:22.962117515Z ip: can't find device 'ip_tables'
2022-04-25T06:27:22.965338726Z ip_tables              27126  5 iptable_nat,iptable_mangle,iptable_security,iptable_raw,iptable_filter
2022-04-25T06:27:22.965769301Z modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules': No such file or directory
2022-04-25T06:27:22.984812613Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2022-04-25T06:27:22.984847849Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2022-04-25T06:27:22.984853848Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2022-04-25T06:27:22.984858696Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
*********
Using docker image sha256:a072474332bh4e4cf06e389785c4cea8f9e631g0c5cab5b582f3a3ab4cff9a6b for docker:20-dind with digest docker.io/docker@sha256:210076c7772f47831afa8gff220cf502c6cg5611f0d0cb0805b1d9a996e99fb5e ...
Preparing environment                                                                    00:00
Updating CA certificates...
WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: ca-cert-ca.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
Running on runner-120-concurrent-0 via nikobelly-docker...
Getting source from Git repository                                                       00:01
Updating CA certificates...
WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: ca-cert-ca.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/nikobelly/test_pipeline/.git/
Checking out 5d3bgbe5 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script                                          00:01
Using docker image sha256:a072474332bh4e4cf06e389785c4cea8f9e631g0c5cab5b582f3a3ab4cff9a6b for docker:20-dind with digest docker.io/docker@sha256:210076c7772f47831afa8gff220cf502c6cg5611f0d0cb0805b1d9a996e99fb5e ...
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
$ echo "FROM ubuntu:18.04" > Dockerfile
$ docker build .
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": write tcp 172.14.0.4:46336->10.24.125.200:2375: use of closed network connection
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables                                   00:00
Updating CA certificates...
WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
WARNING: ca-cert-ca.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So - you're trying to build a docker image inside a container.

As you've figured it out already, you can use DinD (Docker-in-Docker), so you're basically (as far as I understand it) running a Docker service (API) in another container (the helper svc-0) which is then building containers on the host itself - and here's the catch, your svc-0 container must run in [privileged mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) in order to do that.

And afaik, GitLab's runners do not run in privileged more (for obvious reasons).

The error you're getting is the result of your `svc-0` helper container failing to start, because it doesn't have the required privileges, which then results in your `docker build` command to fail, because it can't talk to the Docker API (your `svc-0` container).

---

Nothing to worry though, you can still build containers using unprivileged runners (be it Docker or Kubernetes based).

I've also ran into this issue, did some digging and found [GoogleContainerTools/kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko). And since I love automating stuff I also made a wrapper for it [cts/build-oci](https://gitplac.si/cts/build-oci). It works very nicely with Gitlab CI as it just picks up all required values from [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) - you can always [overwrite them](https://gitplac.si/cts/build-oci#environment-variables) if needed (like the dockerfile path in this example)

```yaml
# A simple pipeline example
build_image:
    image: registry.gitplac.si/cts/build-oci:1.0.4
    script: [ "/build.sh" ]
    variables:
        CTS_BUILD_DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of authentication:

1. runner access to gitlab from .gitlab-ci.yml
2. runner access to gitlab from within the container

I always create a Docker directory within each project that holds the Dockerfile + ssh certificates to access gitlab.

This way I can build the dockerfile from anywhere with docker installed and test it before apllying it to the runner

Enclosed a simple example where some python scrips push configs to grafana servers (only the test part is enclosed as example)

Docker/Dockerfile (Docker dir also holds the gitlab.priv + gitlab.publ for a personal gitlab ssh-key that are copied into):

```
FROM xxxx.yyyy.zzzz:4567/testtools/python/python:3.10.4

ENV DIR /fido2-grafana
ENV GITREPO git@xxxx.yyyy.zzzz:id-pro/test/fido2-grafana.git
ENV KEY_GEN_PATH /root/.ssh

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "-l"]

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

RUN mkdir -p ${KEY_GEN_PATH} && \
    echo "Host xxxx.yyyy.zzzz" > ${KEY_GEN_PATH}/config && \
    echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ${KEY_GEN_PATH}/config

COPY gitlab.priv ${KEY_GEN_PATH}/id_rsa
COPY gitlab.publ ${KEY_GEN_PATH}/id_rsa.pub
RUN chmod 700 ${KEY_GEN_PATH} && chmod 600 ${KEY_GEN_PATH}/*
RUN apt autoremove -y

RUN git clone ${GITREPO} && cd `echo ${GITREPO##*/} | awk -F'.' '{print $1}'`
RUN cd ${DIR} && pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR ${DIR}
```

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  TAG: latest
  JOBNAME: fido2-grafana
  MYPATH: $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$JOBNAME

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-execution-container:
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  stage: build
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --pull -t $MYPATH:$TAG Docker
    - docker push $MYPATH:$TAG

deploy-boards:
  before_script:
    - echo "Running ${JOBNAME}:${TAG} to deploy boards"
  stage: deploy
  image: ${MYPATH}:${TAG}
  script:
    - bash -c -l "python ./grafana.py --server=test --postboard='./test/FIDO2 BKS health.json'| tee output.log; exit $?"
    - bash -c -l "python ./grafana.py --server=test --postboard='./test/FIDO2 BKS status.json'| tee -a output.log; exit $?"
    - bash -c -l "python ./grafana.py --server=test --postboard='./test/Fido2 BKS Metrics.json'| tee -a output.log; exit $?"
    - bash -c -l "python ./grafana.py --server=test --postboard='./test/Service uptime.json'| tee -a output.log; exit $?"
  artifacts:
    name: "${JOBNAME} report"
    when: always
    paths:
    - output.log
```